# connection timed out after 3 runs of node.js cron python script on bluemix cio

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, ibm-cloud

I have a node.js app that runs cron jobs of a python script that was migrated from a remote UNIX box that has been running the script regularly. The app works fine locally.

However, on Bluemix CIO the app runs 3 times , then crashes and restarts and the process is repeated. I would appreciate any insights as to why this is happening.

> > APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in incrementMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='9.16.172.220', port=9443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ibm/iis/igc-rest/v1/search/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopenMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 284, in connectMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 self._validate_conn(conn)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 chunked=chunked)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed outMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 sock.connect(sa)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 raise errMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 ----- Python Traceback -----May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 at ChildProcess. (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:89:9)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 at terminateIfNeeded (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:98:28)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 at PythonShell.parseError (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:184:17)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 ^May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 throw err;May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 timeout=timeoutMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "igc-cloudant_test.py", line 190, in May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopenMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in sendMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 Traceback (most recent call last):May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 Traceback (most recent call last):May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed outMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_connMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 conn = self._new_conn()May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_connMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0/home/vcap/app/server.js:42May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0Error: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='9.16.172.220', port=9443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ibm/iis/igc-rest/v1/search/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_connMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connectionMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connectionMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 Traceback (most recent call last):May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_requestMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 conn.connect()May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.243 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in postMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in sendMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 response = post_search(payload, credentials,cookies)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 dt_response=get_columns_updated_after_time(a_min_ago, credentials,cookies)[0]May 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/app/querybackendutilities_test.py", line 390, in post_searchMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 r=session.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False, auth=(igc_usr, igc_pass),cookies=cookies )May 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)May 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in sendMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "igc-cloudant_test.py", line 72, in get_columns_updated_after_timeMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM
> >     APP/PROC/WEB/0 File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in requestMay 11, 2018 04:08:10.244 PM

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks as though your application is unable to connect at the network level to a third party application.  Please verify that the cloud foundry environment is able to access the network of the third party application.

Comment: it is able to connect and runs correctly for 3 iterations at a time. I only showed the part of the log where it starts to fail

Comment: Actually, I do not think it is making the connection as it is not returning the status code like it is supposed to.